# Reading a text file in python with 200000 lines

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a csv file with 10K lines.
I am able to read :

```
import numpy as np
  features = pd.read_csv("data/kt/features.csv", dtype=np.float64)
  targets = pd.read_csv("data/kt/targets.csv", dtype=np.float64)
   for i in range(len(features)-1):
     yield {
        "inputs": list(features.iloc[i]),
        "targets": list(targets.iloc[i])
        }
```

but now I have text files with 200000 lines . I tried to copy into excel but its telling we number of rows cannot be more than ~120000.

1) Is there a way I can convert my test file with 200000 lines to csv file with out copy /paste?

2) can I have a program to use pandas/or any libraries to read all these lines and get the data in inputs and targets?

Comment: this is not a good use-case for pandas, pandas isn't just a csv reader. Just use the built-in `csv` module for that...

Comment: Anyway, what exactly are you asking? you have a text file with 200000 lines, what is the relevance of excel? Do you need an excel file? You seem to have a text-file that is already formatted as a csv, right? you mention "convert by copy paste"... so just use your text file, *it already is a csv*.

Comment: I have a textfile which I want to convert it to a csv file. how can I convert to a csv file so that I can use pandas. my mistake to use the word csv

Comment: What does that mean **exactly**? What is in your text file that you need to convert?